# long running process new thread win forms vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

I am calling a web service from a windows form(vb.net 4.5) via a button

My problem, when I click the button nothing happens to the progress bar and the interace seems frozen/unresponsive

I believe I need to place the web service call into a thread to accomplish this

Here is what I've got so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
    ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 5
    Dim webservice As New somewebservice.somewsdl
    Dim output(3) As String
    'this method can take 1-10 seconds...
    Try
        output = somewebservice.method()            
    Catch ex As Exception
        txtErrorDesc.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
    ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: [This may be useful.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289496(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: The text is a link, it's just a page on MSDN about multithreading in VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

If you target Framework 4.x, you can use async/await. If the webservice does not offer (awaitable) asynchronous calls, you can wrap the call into an asynchronous call:

```
Private Function foo() As String

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Return "HelloWorld"

End Function

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Console.WriteLine("I am here")
    Console.WriteLine(Await Task(Of String).Run(Function() foo()))
    Console.WriteLine("And now I am here")

End Sub
```

Same could be done with a call to your webservice

```
output = Await Task(Of String()).Run(Function() somewebservice.method())
```

This creates a thread from the ThreadPool and runs your call to the webservice. Your UI thread will not become blocked and when the call to the webservice finishes, the code continues where it was left (at the `Await`).